# Collecting data from JSON obj using underscore to create an array of locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help with this..

I am using underscore and a huge chunk of JSON data and wish to extract all the different event locations..

is it possible to create an array off all the event locations using this structure? (please see image of obj)

I'm not sure how to loop through get the event_location and event_location_id push in to an array (if not already there) for each day -- event...

So basically what I need in the end is a list like..

```
[event_location_id: 1, event_location: somewhere]
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

**NOTE CURRENT ARRAY RESULT [Alberto Montellano]**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .each function of underscore library. http://underscorejs.org/#each

My suggestion would be:

```
var arrayResult = [];
_.each(yourObject.days, function(day, key) {
    _.each(day.events, function(event, key) {
            var obj = {
                event_location_id : event.event_location_id,
                event_location: event.event_location
            };
            arrayResult.push(obj);
      });
  });
```

Your result list will be:

```
 [{event_location_id: 1, event_location: somewhere}, {event_location_id: 2, event_location: somewhere2}, {event_location_id: 3, event_location: somewhere3} ]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It does very much, i posted what the arrayResult looks like for me above - I could loop through this and neaten it up I guess - if I cant find a better of creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness this is my complete solution:

```
 var arrayResult = [];
_.each(yourObject.days, function(day, key) {
    _.each(day.events, function(event, key) {
        var obj = {
            event_location_id : event.event_location_id,
            event_location: event.event_location
        };
        arrayResult.push(obj);
  });
 });


        var uniques = _.map(_.groupBy(arrayResult,function(theEvent){ // returns an unique array of venues
        if( theEvent.event_location_id > 0 ) // exclude non-events e.g. id  = 0..
        {
            return theEvent.event_location_id;// console.log(theEvent.event_location_id);
        }
        }),function(grouped){
            return grouped[0];
        });
```